# Turkey broth cooking in a crockpot for two days

Tags: turkey, broth

I've left turkey broth cooking on low in a crockpot for two days.
Is it still safe to use for soup. Or should I just throw it out?

Answer (score 2):

I just strained my two day turkey stock.

As long as it stayed simmering the entire time it is perfectly safe.

Answer (score 1):

Better than safe, it's great. This is exactly my lazy recipe for chicken stock. Bones in crockpot. Low for 48 hours.